# Python ctypes how to read string modified by C code

Tags: python, c, ctypes

After following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6229675/1279472)  answer, I wrote a C library which I call from python using ctypes. The C library contains a function which takes a `char*` and modifies its contents. I would like to read the contents in Python, however, after calling the library function in Python, I get an empty string even though I see the correct output in the terminal if I include a  `printf` statement in the C code. What am I doing wrong?

C code:

```
void somefunction(char * pythonbuffer)
{
    /* do something */
    printf("%s", pythonbuffer);
}
```

Python code:

```
lib.somefunction.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p] 
lib.somefunction.restype = ctypes.c_void_p 

buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(upper_limit)

lib.somefunction(buffer)

print(buffer.value)
```

Output:
`b''`

Comment: How exactly does `somefunction` modify its parameter `pythonbuffer`?  What did you expect to see happen?

Comment: It calls another library which stores a long string in `pythonbuffer`. If I then print the content in C I get what I expect, but I can't get the same output in Python.

Comment: i guess you want `lib.somefunction(ctypes.POINTER(buffer))`

Comment: @Coldspeed, `POINTER(buffer)` makes no sense, and `pointer(buffer)` would be redundant.

Comment: @Coldspeed , if you look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference) the buffer should be passed as is.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Turns out that the code in the `/* do something */` part somehow changed the adress of `pythonbuffer`. I solved it by using a temporary `char *` and then copying it to `pythonbuffer` with `strcpy`.

Comment: Remember to fix `restype` to be `None` instead of returning a garbage `c_void_p` pointer.

Comment: Yep, I did that.